# How is it possible a 404 response just only in IE8?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, internet-explorer-8, spring-security

I have an Spring application (with Spring Security and Spring MVC) deployed in a Tomcat server. The application works perfecty in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9.

I have a weird problem with IE8. The login screen loads, and (as I can see in server logs) the session is open when username and password are provided. Once the user is logged, and the browser is redirected to the main page, a 404 error is returned by the server.

As IE8 developer tools doesn't have a net panel, I have used Fiddler to monitor http connections. I thought that it could be happening that it was doing a wrong request during page loading but it was the main page request wich is responsing with 404.

How is it possible that the server responses with 404 to the main page request just only in IE8?

Thank you.

Edited:

Those are the request header for IE8 and Firefox respectively:

```
GET /myWebApp/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: es-ES
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: dev.mydomain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABA1382304002F894ABDFCC2442FA5F8; SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=NGUxMTZlOTY3OGM0OTgxNDY4NDczOTlkOjEzMjQ1ODMwMzU0MDI6OWZiYzdhYjY1ODY2Mzc3YmI0Yzc5YTMzMWI5NDhjNTg
```

--

```
GET /myWebApp/ HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es,chrome://global/locale/intl.properties;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=7FD3B02252E2FCBC9BE7249AFD84F541; SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=NGUxMmYxMTgzMmRjZTM0NzYyMWVjOWEwOjEzMjQ1ODMwMTA1MTU6MzFiYzU4OGQ4NTMwN2Y3M2I4YmQzN2M0NzY2MzcwZjI
```

Comment: if you're already using Fiddler you could compare the requests (including headers) sent by IE8 and a working browser. Unlock and start editing the IE8 request until you get something that works. This obviously won't fix the problem for your users but at least shows you where to look. Perhaps for some reason IE8 isn't sending a cookie related to the login when it requests your home page?

Comment: Thank you I've done as you said and I don't find any clue about what is the problem. I'll edit the post adding the headers in both cases.

Comment: I've discovered that changing 'Accept' in IE8 request to the one in Firefox request (Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8) it works so I supose I have to configure my app to the 'Accept' value IE8 is sending.

Comment: That sounds odd, but perhaps your server thinks it can't represent the requested resource in a format that is Accept-ed by IE (even though your IE header includes the wildcard '*/*'), and so returns a 404. I'm guessing this is a server configuration issue rather than a problem in your application (though in Tomcat I am already out of my depth). Perhaps the order is causing the problem - an attempt is made to return a 'higher-priority' format than text/html, according to the order of the IE accept header contents? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that the problem was about "Accept" I have revised the MVC Controller classes mappings and I have finaly found the issue. Somehow this was the way that the main page was mapped in MVC so it didn't work whith the IE8 header attribute:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/", headers = "Accept=text/*" )
```

I have learned a hard lesson today. ;-)

Comment: This helped me - I couldn't figure out why each time I'd go to "/" IE would try to download a spreadsheet (I have another page where a spreadsheet is generated), yet in FF it would work fine. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I didn't understand, i have to add this line somewhere?